# in a codeigniter controller load->view how can I add a Anchor Tags To Jump To the Specific Location

Tags: php, codeigniter, tags, anchor

In a codeigniter controller how can I add a Anchor Tags To Jump To the Specific location in a page view.
Example in a normal link : Link to access in the section

In the codeigniter controller I'm using :
$data['title'] = 'Page view title';
$this->load->view('controller/page_view#destination', $data); but not working.

It works with redirect(controller/page_view#destination) but dont pass on $data.

I need your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 3):

Pass one more variable in `$data` array.

```
$data['pageSection'] = 'destination';
$this->load->view('controller/page_view', $data);
```

Then in view file make JS code block that will scroll to that section:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#<?php echo $pageSection;?>').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

It need to be in same view file, not in separate JS file for variable to be available.

Comment: @Liste-cadeauxPourTous #SOreadytohelp Don't hesitate to accept the answer. :)